Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Can anyone help me resolve it?
Good evening, I know almost nothing about programming, but when compiling an application "that apparently was ready" I come across this error:
Error Log
[16/05/2024 06:54:06] Exception in thread "Network Thread" [16/05/2024 06:54:06] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
[16/05/2024 06:54:06]   at br.com.mundoerinia.engine.nio.MessageQueue.receiveFromSocket(MessageQueue.java:144)
[16/05/2024 06:54:06]   at br.com.mundoerinia.engine.nio.MessageQueue.process(MessageQueue.java:130)
[16/05/2024 06:54:06]   at br.com.mundoerinia.engine.nio.NetworkThread.run(NetworkThread.java:111)

file code
package engine.nio;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.BufferOverflowException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import infra.util.Log;

import engine.networkserver.NetWorkUtils;
import engine.utils.IgnisTimer;


public class MessageQueue implements NetworkInterface {
    
    private static int SEND_BUFFER_SIZE = 20000;

    public static int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 3000;

    
    private static int KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT = 3000;

    
    private SocketChannel socketChannel;


    private NetWorkBufferEncoder bufferEncoder;


    private NetWorkBufferDecoder bufferDecoder;


    private ByteBuffer receiveBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(NetWorkUtils.getMaxPacketSize());


    private ByteBuffer sendBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(SEND_BUFFER_SIZE);


    private ArrayList<byte[]> sendList = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    
    private long lLastPacketTime = Long.MAX_VALUE;

    
    private long lLastKeepAliveTime = IgnisTimer.currentTimeMillis();

    
    private long lConnectionTime = IgnisTimer.currentTimeMillis();

    
    private int iTotalBytesSent = 0;

    
    private int iTotalBytesReceived = 0;

    private long lLastFrameTime = 0;

    
    private boolean bIsConnected = true;

    
    private boolean bSendKeepAlive = false;

    /** construtor */
    public MessageQueue(SocketChannel channel) throws IOException {
        socketChannel = channel;

        Socket socket = channel.socket();
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);

        bufferEncoder = new NetWorkBufferEncoder(this);
        bufferDecoder = new NetWorkBufferDecoder(this);
    }

    public void process() {
        if (bIsConnected) {
            receiveFromSocket();

            sendToSocket();
        } else {
            
            disconnect();
        }

        
        lLastFrameTime = IgnisTimer.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void sendToSocket() {
        try {
            synchronized (sendBuffer) {
                int iBytesToSend = sendBuffer.position();

                
                if (iBytesToSend > 0) {

                    lLastKeepAliveTime = IgnisTimer.currentTimeMillis();

                    sendBuffer.flip(); 

                    
                    socketChannel.socket().setSendBufferSize(iBytesToSend);

                    
                    int iBytesSent = socketChannel.write(sendBuffer);

                    

                    sendBuffer.compact(); 

                    if (iBytesSent > 0) {
                        lLastPacketTime = IgnisTimer.currentTimeMillis();
                        iTotalBytesSent += iBytesSent;
                    } else
                        checkConnectionTimeout();
                } else 
                if (!addSendList())
                    checkKeepAliveTimeout();
            }
        } catch (ClosedChannelException cce) {
            bIsConnected = false;
            
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            bIsConnected = false;
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            bIsConnected = false;
            
        }
    }

    
    private void receiveFromSocket() {
        try {
            
            int iBytesRead = socketChannel.read(receiveBuffer);

            if (iBytesRead > 0) {
            
                receiveBuffer.flip();
                byte[] newData = new byte[iBytesRead];
                receiveBuffer.get(newData, 0, iBytesRead);
                
                
                bufferDecoder.gotNewDataFromSocket(newData);

                
                receiveBuffer.clear();

                iTotalBytesReceived += iBytesRead;
            }
        } catch (ClosedChannelException cce) {
            bIsConnected = false;
            Log.error(cce, "Conexão terminando por ClosedChannelException !!!");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            bIsConnected = false;
            Log.error(ioe, "Conexão terminando por IOException");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            bIsConnected = false;
            Log.error(e, "Conexão terminando por Exception");
        }
    }

    
    public void addEncodedMessage(byte[] b) {
        synchronized (sendBuffer) {
            ensureBufferCapacity(b.length);

            try {
                
                while (!sendList.isEmpty()) {
                    
                    sendBuffer.put((byte[]) sendList.get(0));

                    
                    sendList.remove(0);

                    
                }

                
                sendBuffer.put(b, 0, b.length);
            } catch (BufferOverflowException e) {
                
                sendList.add(b);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
            }
        }
    }

    
    private void checkConnectionTimeout() {
        if (IgnisTimer.currentTimeMillis() > lLastPacketTime + CONNECTION_TIMEOUT) {
            
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    
    private void checkKeepAliveTimeout() {
        if (bSendKeepAlive)
            if (IgnisTimer.currentTimeMillis() > lLastKeepAliveTime + KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT)
                bufferEncoder.encodeAndSend(NetWorkBufferDecoder.KEEP_ALIVE_PCKT, null);
        
    }

    
    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            socketChannel.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            
        }

        
        NetworkThread.instance.endConnection(this);

        
        bIsConnected = false;
    }

    
    public void ensureBufferCapacity(int size) {
        if (size > sendBuffer.capacity()) {
            try {
                byte[] bufferBytes = sendBuffer.array();
                ByteBuffer newBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
                newBuffer.put(bufferBytes, 0, sendBuffer.position());
                sendBuffer = newBuffer;
            } catch (BufferOverflowException e) {
                
            }

            
        }
    }

    
    private boolean addSendList() {
        boolean added = false;

        try {
            
            while (!sendList.isEmpty()) {
                
                sendBuffer.put((byte[]) sendList.get(0));

                
                sendList.remove(0);
                added = true;

                
            }
        } catch (BufferOverflowException e) {
        }

        return added;
    }

    
    public void enableKeepAlive() {
        bSendKeepAlive = true;
    }

    
    public boolean sendMessage(byte[] b) {
        
        bufferEncoder.encodeAndSend(b);
        return true;
    }

    
    public byte[] popMessage() {
        return bufferDecoder.popMessage();
    }

    
    public String getClientAddress() {
        SocketAddress sa = socketChannel.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress();

        if (sa != null)
            return sa.toString();

        return "MessageQueue -> not connected !!!";
    }

    
    public SocketAddress getRemoteSocketAddress() {
        return socketChannel.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress();
    }

    
    public int getConnectionTimeSecs() {
        return (int) ((IgnisTimer.currentTimeMillis() - lConnectionTime) / 1000);
    }

    
    public long getConnectionTimeMillis() {
        return IgnisTimer.currentTimeMillis() - lConnectionTime;
    }

    
    public long getConnectionStartTime() {
        return lConnectionTime;
    }

    
    public int getTotalBytesSent() {
        return iTotalBytesSent;
    }

    
    public int getTotalBytesReceived() {
        return iTotalBytesReceived;
    }

    
    public NetWorkBufferEncoder getEncoder() {
        return bufferEncoder;
    }

    
    public boolean isConnected() {
        return bIsConnected;
    }

    
    public void setLastFrameTime(long time) {
        lLastFrameTime = time;
    }

    
    public long lastFrameTime() {
        return (lLastFrameTime);
    }

} 

If anyone can help me with this, I would be immensely grateful! Thank you very much for the time guys! and excuse my English, I use Google Translate! =x
OBS.: My Topic was closed because there is an open topic explaining how to solve it, but I don't know how to solve it, if anyone can tell me how to do it, literally thank you!

"... if anyone can tell me how to do it ..." - You need to make sure that you use the same dependency JAR files at compile time and runtime.  Solve THAT.  We can't solve it for you (i.e. tell you what to do) because you didn't provide enough context.
